# Vite + React how to integrate a HTML file and JS files

Tags: javascript, vite

I am using Vite with React + JavaScript for my frontend. So far, I've set up a couple of pages using jsx files and the React Router to bring those pages into `app.jsx`

I have a dynamic HTML file from a separate project which contains a bunch of JavaScript, CSS, UI displays etc.

I'd like to integrate this HTML file and serve it on a specific path like: `localhost:3000/test`

The HTML file must be publicly available to the client as well as two related JS files so they must be relative to each other.

My `app.jsx` file as-is (includes a placeholder for the HTML file):

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './routes/Home';
import About from './routes/About';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
                <Route path='/about' element={<About />}/>
                <Route path='/test' element={MY-HTML-FILE}/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
  }
export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by discovering what the vite.config.js file does.

You can serve up different entry points.

My answer was to use rollup

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  root,
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(root, 'index.html'),
        test: resolve(root, 'test', 'test.html')
      }

    }
  }


})
```